# Using rscala eval function for returning values to Scala not working

Tags: r, scala

I am using rscala package to write R in Scala. There seems to be an issue when I want to pull the results back to Scala. 
Here is the code I am trying -

```
import org.ddahl.rscala._
import breeze.stats.distributions._
import breeze.linalg._
val R = RClient()
R.eval("library('diptest')")
R.eval("library('plyr')")
R.eval("comp1_test_result <- read.csv('C:/Users/vamallya/Downloads/multimodal/cleaned_multimodel_test.csv')")
R.eval("dip_test_op_2 <- ddply(comp1_test_result, .(testName),function(df) {data.frame(p_val = dip.test(df$measured)$p.value)})")
R.eval("bimodal_results <- dip_test_op_2[dip_test_op_2$p_val < 0.05,]")
val res = R.evalS1("bimodal_results$testName")
```

When I try to obtain the results it gives me an error called unsupported datatype. The result I am looking for is an Array of Strings. I tired all different types of eval but none of them seem to work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok So I solved my issue by converting the R column to a vector.

I achieved this by obtaining res as

```
val res = R.evalS1("as.vector(bimodal_results$testName)")
```

This got me the required array.